# Eclipse .metadata\.plugins disk space

Tags: eclipse, plugins, metadata, diskspace, eclipse-metadata

Eclipse's .metadata/.plugins seems to consume way too much space (235 MB), is there something I can safely throw away and still be happy?

I archive my source root, and this seems to take away all my space. This is a project with several Java projects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The plugins store your workspace configuration. If you delete them then your workspace may become unusable.

Depending on your plugins used and what you are doing you can probably delete some of them. Personally I'm regularly cleaning some of the plugins.

What I delete:

1. maven repository files/indexes
2. project indexes
3. Copies of deployed files to application servers.

I'd suggest you get a tool like [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) and check, which plugins use up your space and maybe by name e.g. `index` you figure out that this plugin can be safely deleted.

Answer (score 34):

In my case 85% of the workspace is occupied by the m2e plugin indexes. More information on that can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178342/caching-the-repository-index-in-m2eclipse) thread.
You can disable it by adjusting plugin configuration parameters as shown on the image bellow:
[image]

**Then you can remove .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core/nexus directory from your workspace.**

Comment: Are there any downsides to disabling Nexus?  That is, will any functionality be lost, or will it slow down builds?

Answer (score 2):

Generally web apps are deployed in one of the directories in .metadata and that's generallay the reason of large size

```
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core
```

Answer (score 0):

There is stuff associated with launch configs in .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.  This can often accumulate a lot and can be safely deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,
The following directory was with big size.
.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core