# Command line Maven and m2eclipse work together?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I want to save disk space (SSD) as well as maven processing time.
I have however the impression that my command line maven (on Arch Linux installed with package manager pacman) and my Eclipse Maven plugin don't work together, because I have both a big ~/.m2 folder (2GB) as well as a big workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core folder (500 MB).

Is my impression correct that they are separated and thus do everything the other did again, wasting both space and time, and if yes, is there a way to connect these two together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ~/.m2 directory is the local maven repository where all you project dependencies files are downloaded in a structured way. Its  same for both command line maven and eclipse maven. The directory workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core only has files related to m2e plugin metadata & it doesn't have the repository files like .m2 directory.

The local maven repository remains same for command line as well as m2e until specified. you can read more on maven repositories [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)

Comment: But why is the plugin folder so big then with more than 500 MB? That is way more than Eclipse alone.

Comment: The plugins store your workspace information as well as web-apps data hence the size is large. for more information please read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539841/eclipse-metadata-plugins-disk-space